# Android : how to find band width of a WiFi channel programmatically?

Tags: android

In my App, am using [ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) to get the list of networks. How do I find the bandwidth of the networks (say is it 22MHz or 40MHz etc) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049030/android-wifi-bandwidth

Comment: This question is asking about literal bandwidth, not bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the range of bandwidth by using the below functions but not the exact bandwidth.

```
   public static void printBandwidthOfConnection(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        Log.i("Range",rangeOfConnection(info.getType(),info.getSubtype())));
    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return string
     */
    public static String rangeOfConnection(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return "wifi";
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return  "50-100 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return " 14-64 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return "50-100 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return "400-1000 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return "600-1400 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return  "100 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return "2-14 Mbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return "700-1700 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return "1-23 Mbps"
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return "400-7000 kbps";
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
                return " 1-2 Mbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                return "5 Mbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                return "10-20 Mbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                return "25 kbps";
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                return "10+ Mbps";
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is about the width of the wifi band, not cellular network type.